# golang regexp FindStringSubmatch() doesn't return the correct last group

Tags: go

I am using go1.10 darwin/amd64, here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    raw := "012 abc 012"
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`(\d+).*(\d+)`)
    m := r.FindStringSubmatch(raw)
    fmt.Printf("len(m)=%v\n%v\n%v\n%v\n", len(m), m[0], m[1], m[2])
}
```

Output is:

> len(m)=3
>
> 012 abc 012
>
> 012
>
> 2

You can also run it here: https://play.golang.org/p/i2zlhClB72e

I expect that the output of m[2] is "012" but not "2".

Can anyone let me know where the issue is? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are greedy, so `.*` will match `01` leaving just `2` to match the final `\d+`.

You probably want to change your expression to something like the following: `(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+)$` to match a sequence of digits (captured), anything but a sequence of digits, a sequence of digits (captured), and the end of line.

The same code for the rest will print what you expected:

```
len(m)=3
012 abc 012
012
012
```

Comment: Wow, you are a genius. With your reminding I tried it like this "r := regexp.MustCompile(`(\d+).*?(\d+)`)", then it also works. Thanks a lot!